# Google Flights (QPX Express) API -- Multiple origin cities/multiple origin dates

Tags: google-qpx-express-api

Does anyone know if there is a way to send multiple origin cities via one request? Or search multiple date ranges on one request? I'm looking for the cheapest flight in a period of time (I have flexible holidays) and live between two moderately sized airports, and really don't want to send multiple requests for each one. Is there at least a way I could search multiple origin airports on the same one? I've tried having my destination as a pure string, as well as as a list.

Things I've tried:

```
'airport1, airport2'

['airport1', 'airport2']
```

Where airport1 and airport2 are, of course, the airport codes for the ones I'm searching for. If I do the list method, it just searches whichever one is first, not the second one.

I would just send the requests, but it's slow and costs $0.03 a pop...which adds up quickly if searching every 2 hours!